# I want to use ng-contextmenu on my html page for providing different menu items. But my JS class is not getting called.

Tags: html, angularjs

This is my html class, I have used one example from net for understanding how it's works.

```
<form>
<div ng-controller="ListController">
    <div>
        <strong>Gold: </strong>
        {{player.gold}}
    </div>
    <div class="list-group">
         <a href="#"
            class="list-group-item"
            ng-repeat="item in items"
            context-menu="menuOptions">
             <span class="badge">{{item.cost}}</span>
             {{item.name}}
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

This is controller :

```
controller('ListController', ['$scope',
                                  function ($scope) {
    $scope.player = {
        gold: 100
    };
    $scope.items = [
        { name: 'Small Health Potion', cost: 4 },
        { name: 'Small Mana Potion', cost: 5 },
        { name: 'Iron Short Sword', cost: 12 }
    ];
    $scope.menuOptions = [
        ['Buy', function ($itemScope) {
            $scope.player.gold -= $itemScope.item.cost;
        }],
        null,
        ['Sell', function ($itemScope) {
            $scope.player.gold += $itemScope.item.cost;
        }]
    ];
}
]);
```

This is my JS file, which is being used for contextmenu:

```
var app = angular.module("contextMenu",[]);
 app.directive('contextMenu', function ($parse) {
        var renderContextMenu = function ($scope, event, options) {
            if (!$) { var $ = angular.element; }
            $(event.currentTarget).addClass('context');
            var $contextMenu = $('<div>');
            $contextMenu.addClass('dropdown clearfix');
            var $ul = $('<ul>');
            $ul.addClass('dropdown-menu');
            $ul.attr({ 'role': 'menu' });
            $ul.css({
                display: 'block',
                position: 'absolute',
                left: event.pageX + 'px',
                top: event.pageY + 'px'
            });
            angular.forEach(options, function (item, i) {
                var $li = $('<li>');
                if (item === null) {
                    $li.addClass('divider');
                } else {
                    $a = $('<a>');
                    $a.attr({ tabindex: '-1', href: '#' });
                    $a.text(typeof item[0] == 'string' ? item[0] : item[0].call($scope, $scope));
                    $li.append($a);
                    $li.on('click', function ($event) {
                        $event.preventDefault();
                        $scope.$apply(function () {
                            $(event.currentTarget).removeClass('context');
                            $contextMenu.remove();
                            item[1].call($scope, $scope);
                        });
                    });
                }
                $ul.append($li);
            });
            $contextMenu.append($ul);
            var height = Math.max(
                document.body.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight,
                document.body.offsetHeight, document.documentElement.offsetHeight,
                document.body.clientHeight, document.documentElement.clientHeight
            );
            $contextMenu.css({
                width: '100%',
                height: height + 'px',
                position: 'absolute',
                top: 0,
                left: 0,
                zIndex: 9999
            });
            $(document).find('body').append($contextMenu);
            $contextMenu.on("mousedown", function (e) {
                if ($(e.target).hasClass('dropdown')) {
                    $(event.currentTarget).removeClass('context');
                    $contextMenu.remove();
                }
            }).on('contextmenu', function (event) {
                $(event.currentTarget).removeClass('context');
                event.preventDefault();
                $contextMenu.remove();
            });
        };
        return function ($scope, element, attrs) {
            element.on('contextmenu', function (event) {
                $scope.$apply(function () {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var options = $scope.$eval(attrs.contextMenu);
                    if (options instanceof Array) {
                        renderContextMenu($scope, event, options);
                    } else {
                        throw '"' + attrs.contextMenu + '" not an array';
                    }
                });
            });
        };
    });
```

But this code is not working for me. My debug point never comes on contextmenu js file. And I am getting default window menu on right click.

Can anyone please suggest what I am doing wrong or missing in this. It would be a great help.

Comment: Have you specified ng-app on the top of your html. ng-app="contextMenu"?

Comment: No, i haven't. I specified it. Still it's not working. My js is in other package and my html is in another. Does it make any difference.?

Comment: Is there any library file, which I need to use for adding context menu.?

Comment: Have a look at my answer below and give a try. Let me know the outcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to create a master app.js file to define your modules something like below. The file needs to be loaded first.

```
(function () {
    var module = angular.module('app', [
        'contextMenu',
        'menu'        
    ]);
})();
```

Now the file which holds controller needs to be something like below.

```
(function () {
    var module = angular.module('menu');

    module.controller('ListController', [
     '$scope'
     function ($scope) {
        //Your controller code goes here
     }]);
})();
```

Your html needs to be something like below.

```
<body ng-app="app">
//Your html goes here
</body>
```

Your js files needs to be added in below order.

- Angularjs
- app.js
- menu.js

That's all i can say for now.

Comment: I was missing the entry of contextmenu js file in rulesapp file

Comment: Its not showing properly when the last item clicked (at page bottom) and right of the item.
It is expanding the context menu towards right. 

Is there any solution for this?